# Variable description table

Tags: tables, longtable

I want to create a table with variable description. First, I the table shown below has really small font and text is not wrapped. And second, I need to let the table continue in the next page. How can I fix these problems?

[image]

```
\begin{table}[!htbp] 
\fontsize{11}{9}\selectfont 
  \caption{Description of Variables used in this Study} 
 \label{table: vardescription}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ l | p{13cm} }
 \hline \hline

\textbf{\normalsize Code} & \textbf{\normalsize Definition and source}  \\
 \hline 


\textbf{exportsgr} & Exports of goods and services (annual \% growth) retrieved from World Bank. \\ \hline 


\textbf{importsgr} & Imports of goods and services (annual \% growth) retrieved from World Bank.\\ \hline 


\textbf{gr\_tot} & Terms of trade change over previous year (in \%).  Data for terms of trade are collected from theglobaleconomy.com  and Kaminsky and Reinhart online database. Since variables have two different base years, the base year for both was changed to 2000 to have the same base year. And then the change is calculated as below.  

\begin{equation}
gr\_tot_{i,t} = (\frac{tot_{i,t}- tot_{i,t-1}}{tot_{i,t-1}})100
\end{equation}
\\ \hline 




\toprule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{table}
```

Comment: I would not write variable names in bold font.

Comment: I'd suggest `xltabular` to make sure the table fits into the textwidth instead of manually setting the width of the second column. This will also allow the table to continue over multiple pages.

Comment: Is xltabular  package or command?

Comment: @Arbnor: An environment from the eponymous package. I have added an answer using said package and environment.

Comment: @Arbnor You find the [xltabular on CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/xltabular).

Answer (score 2):

Here are two different examples of your table using `xltabular` to enable page breaking and to make sure the table fits into the textwidth:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}


\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{ l | X }
  \caption{Description of Variables used in this Study} 
 \label{table: vardescription}\\
 \hline \hline

\textbf{\normalsize Code} & \textbf{\normalsize Definition and source}  \\
 \hline 
\endfirsthead
 \hline \hline

\textbf{\normalsize Code} & \textbf{\normalsize Definition and source}  \\
 \hline 
\endhead

\textbf{exportsgr} & Exports of goods and services (annual \% growth) retrieved from World Bank. \\ \hline 


\textbf{importsgr} & Imports of goods and services (annual \% growth) retrieved from World Bank.\\ \hline 


\textbf{gr\_tot} & Terms of trade change over previous year (in \%).  Data for terms of trade are collected from theglobaleconomy.com  and Kaminsky and Reinhart online database. Since variables have two different base years, the base year for both was changed to 2000 to have the same base year. And then the change is calculated as below.  

\begin{equation}
gr\_tot_{i,t} = (\frac{tot_{i,t}- tot_{i,t-1}}{tot_{i,t-1}})100
\end{equation}
\\ \hline 
\textbf{exportsgr} & Exports of goods and services (annual \% growth) retrieved from World Bank. \\ \hline 


\textbf{importsgr} & Imports of goods and services (annual \% growth) retrieved from World Bank.\\ \hline 


\textbf{gr\_tot} & Terms of trade change over previous year (in \%).  Data for terms of trade are collected from theglobaleconomy.com  and Kaminsky and Reinhart online database. Since variables have two different base years, the base year for both was changed to 2000 to have the same base year. And then the change is calculated as below.  

\begin{equation}
gr\_tot_{i,t} = (\frac{tot_{i,t}- tot_{i,t-1}}{tot_{i,t-1}})100
\end{equation}
\\ \hline 
\textbf{exportsgr} & Exports of goods and services (annual \% growth) retrieved from World Bank. \\ \hline 


\textbf{importsgr} & Imports of goods and services (annual \% growth) retrieved from World Bank.\\ \hline 


\textbf{gr\_tot} & Terms of trade change over previous year (in \%).  Data for terms of trade are collected from theglobaleconomy.com  and Kaminsky and Reinhart online database. Since variables have two different base years, the base year for both was changed to 2000 to have the same base year. And then the change is calculated as below.  

\begin{equation}
gr\_tot_{i,t} = (\frac{tot_{i,t}- tot_{i,t-1}}{tot_{i,t-1}})100
\end{equation}
\\ \hline 
\textbf{exportsgr} & Exports of goods and services (annual \% growth) retrieved from World Bank. \\ \hline 


\textbf{importsgr} & Imports of goods and services (annual \% growth) retrieved from World Bank.\\ \hline 


\textbf{gr\_tot} & Terms of trade change over previous year (in \%).  Data for terms of trade are collected from theglobaleconomy.com  and Kaminsky and Reinhart online database. Since variables have two different base years, the base year for both was changed to 2000 to have the same base year. And then the change is calculated as below.  

\begin{equation}
gr\_tot_{i,t} = (\frac{tot_{i,t}- tot_{i,t-1}}{tot_{i,t-1}})100
\end{equation}
\\ \hline 

\end{xltabular}


\newpage

\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{ l  X }
  \caption{Description of Variables used in this Study} 
 \label{table: vardescription}\\
\toprule
 Code & Definition and source  \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\toprule
 Code & Definition and source  \\
\midrule
\endhead
\bottomrule
\endfoot

exportsgr & Exports of goods and services (annual \% growth) retrieved from World Bank. \\ \addlinespace 


importsgr & Imports of goods and services (annual \% growth) retrieved from World Bank.\\   \addlinespace


gr\_tot & Terms of trade change over previous year (in \%).  Data for terms of trade are collected from theglobaleconomy.com  and Kaminsky and Reinhart online database. Since variables have two different base years, the base year for both was changed to 2000 to have the same base year. And then the change is calculated as below.  

\begin{equation}
gr\_tot_{i,t} = (\frac{tot_{i,t}- tot_{i,t-1}}{tot_{i,t-1}})100
\end{equation}
\\  \addlinespace

exportsgr & Exports of goods and services (annual \% growth) retrieved from World Bank. \\  \addlinespace


importsgr & Imports of goods and services (annual \% growth) retrieved from World Bank.\\ \addlinespace 


gr\_tot & Terms of trade change over previous year (in \%).  Data for terms of trade are collected from theglobaleconomy.com  and Kaminsky and Reinhart online database. Since variables have two different base years, the base year for both was changed to 2000 to have the same base year. And then the change is calculated as below.  

\begin{equation}
gr\_tot_{i,t} = (\frac{tot_{i,t}- tot_{i,t-1}}{tot_{i,t-1}})100
\end{equation}
\\  \addlinespace

exportsgr & Exports of goods and services (annual \% growth) retrieved from World Bank. \\ \addlinespace 


importsgr & Imports of goods and services (annual \% growth) retrieved from World Bank.\\  \addlinespace


gr\_tot & Terms of trade change over previous year (in \%).  Data for terms of trade are collected from theglobaleconomy.com  and Kaminsky and Reinhart online database. Since variables have two different base years, the base year for both was changed to 2000 to have the same base year. And then the change is calculated as below.  

\begin{equation}
gr\_tot_{i,t} = (\frac{tot_{i,t}- tot_{i,t-1}}{tot_{i,t-1}})100
\end{equation}
\\  

exportsgr & Exports of goods and services (annual \% growth) retrieved from World Bank. \\  \addlinespace


importsgr & Imports of goods and services (annual \% growth) retrieved from World Bank.\\  \addlinespace


gr\_tot & Terms of trade change over previous year (in \%).  Data for terms of trade are collected from theglobaleconomy.com  and Kaminsky and Reinhart online database. Since variables have two different base years, the base year for both was changed to 2000 to have the same base year. And then the change is calculated as below.  

\begin{equation}
gr\_tot_{i,t} = (\frac{tot_{i,t}- tot_{i,t-1}}{tot_{i,t-1}})100
\end{equation}
\\  

\end{xltabular}


\end{document}
```

Comment: If the test shall fill the line width, you have to remove the side bearing of the table. If not, the text is indented from the left and right margin with a `\tabcolsep`. Also, using a `l`-column means that one long expression in the first column, will result in a narrow second (X) column. If first column is set in bold, you should redirect a `\bfseries` instead of using `\textbf`.

Comment: I suggest changeing the first lines of your table to: `\newcolumntype{F}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\bfseries\hsize=0.2\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\hsize=1.8\hsize}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{} F  X @{}} `  Defining two new column types F and L which is reltative to each other.